# How can I save my best model which have the highest f1_score in kfold?

Tags: python

I'm trying to save the best model after using KFold. Is there any way I can save the best model depend on f1_score of each fold?

Comment: Which model are you talking about.?

Comment: It's a LSTM model @SreeramTP

Comment: your question is so vague. Which library are you using.? Keras.? TF.? Pytorch.?

Comment: I'm using Keras anyway i found the way to solve it. Thank you for helping me.I'll leave the answer in case anyone want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PICKLE library in python to save your model as .pkl file. You can reuse this model file when ever you would like to use. It's a model persistent.

Please let me know if you have any questions. I would be very happy to help you.

Comment: Yes i know Pickle can help me save the model as file but i want to save only the best model with the highest f1_score in each fold while you running model

Comment: It depends on the library you are using. If you are using Sklearn library and for logistic regression problem, use GridSearchCV method where we need to pass CV (cross validation folds), grid parameters (C, Penalty - L1(Lasso), L2(Ridge)). So that you can fit the model with these hyper parameter optimization and save with pickle. Please let me know if you need any sample code, i would be very happy to provide.